# How to switch boolean value in Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to write simple method which will switch value of a field (called 'isAgreed') from true to false and vice versa.
I started with an example found on the web, but now I am stuck.
How can I change the following code to achieve my goal:

```
updateNegotiationVariable(data) {

      return this.firestore
        .collection("negotiationVariables")
        .doc(data.payload.doc.id)
        .set({isAgreed: true }, { merge: true });
    }
```

This is my first app using Firestore so I am sorry for trivial question, but I couldn't find answer on the web. I develop simple angular application using Firestore database.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to explain what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: My expectations is that if I launch this method it will check if isAgreed is true and then change to false. And when it occurs to be false it will change to true. Currently, it only changes value one way, from false to true.

Comment: All your code above *says* is to set isAgreed: true - there's no conditional expressed here.  Which part of the above code did you think was a conditional?  {merge: true} is *not* a conditional - it just says to merge the new field(s) with any existing fields - only isAgreed will be overwritten.

Comment: My question is how to add this part. The issue is not that it is not working fine, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it. My question was naive.
This is the solution if anybody is interested:

```
updateNegotiationVariable(data) {
  let isA = data.payload.doc.data().isAgreed
  console.log(data.payload.doc.data().isAgreed)
  if (isA == true) { isA = false } else { isA = true }
  return this.firestore
    .collection("negotiationVariables")
    .doc(data.payload.doc.id)
    .set({isAgreed: isA }, { merge: true });
}
```